# Wi-Fi on Lenovo 330 is not working after updating kernel to 4.19.0

Tags: networking, wireless, kernel, lenovo, realtek-wireless

I have updated my kernel to 4.19.0 on Ubuntu 18.10. I have downloaded from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.19/ header, image, module files in deb packages and the command

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

After the reboot I can't find my Wi-Fi showing in the settings menu. My Wi-Fi is Realtek rtl8821ce. How can I get my Wi-Fi back?

Do i need to rollback my kernel or does it has any solution?
 - And adding to that my touchpad is also not working?

Comment: You could try rebuilding your driver. https://github.com/endlessm/linux/tree/master/drivers/net/wireless/rtl8821ce
I've had problems after kernel updates that rebuilding has fixed. But Ubuntu  is still at 4.18 -- at least my just updated 18.10 is at 4.18.

Comment: I have downloaded from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.19/ header, image, module files in deb packages and the command sudo dpkg -i *.deb